# How Can I Select One Word In TextBox and change its color in C#

Tags: c#

How Can I Select the wrong spelling Word In Text Box and change its color ?

```
if (!SuggestStrings(char.ToLower(t.Text[Tempindex - 1]), Dic, First, Last))
                        {
                            //Search.SelectionStart = indexSentence - indexWord;
                            //Search.SelectionLength = indexWord;
                            Search.Text.Substring(indexSentence - indexWord, indexWord);
                            Search.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11, FontStyle.Underline);
                            Search.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            t.SelectionLength = 0;
                            foundWord = false;



               }
```

Comment: You need to use a RichTextBox. Tons of examples here..

Comment: do i have to use RichTextBox ?

Comment: Yes, no multiple colors in a normal TextBox.